# Cygwin + zsh: Home and End keys not working

Tags: windows, cygwin, zsh, mintty

I cannot get Home and End keys to work for zsh under Cygwin. Various sources seem to suggest that

```
bindkey '\e[1~' beginning-of-line
bindkey '\e[4~' end-of-line
```

will fix the problem but this does not work for me. Strangely, after I enter

```
bindkey "\e[3~" delete-char
```

the Delete button starts working (before that it just outputs ~).

Does anyone has an idea what is going on?

I'm on Windows XP and I am using the latest versions of the available Cygwin packages.

**UPDATE**: This seems to be a problem with mintty, if I run cygwin.bat that launches the Windows command prompt, then everything works fine. Maybe it is related to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=59)?

Comment: If you call `read`, what does it output when you press `Home` and `End` respectively?

Comment: If i run read from the terminal, and then press Home, the cursor jumps at the top of the screen. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Then you have to configure your terminal to actually pass these commands to the shell. No idea how this works in Windows though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With the help of the mintty mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/mintty-discuss/v4b86DBNI80) I found the answer. The lines that I need to add to .zshrc are

```
bindkey '\e[H' beginning-of-line
bindkey '\e[F' end-of-line
```

Answer (score 5):

Here my complete list of additional useful bindings (corrected to remove colons from commands).

```
# ctrl-left/right
bindkey "\e[1;5C" forward-word
bindkey "\e[1;5D" backward-word

# ctrl-backspace/delete
bindkey "\C-_" backward-kill-word
bindkey "\e[3;5~" kill-word

# alt-backspace
bindkey "\e\d" undo

bindkey "\e[3~" delete-char
bindkey '\e[H' beginning-of-line
bindkey '\e[F' end-of-line
```